# Aurelia bug with bindable in combination with class decorator?

Tags: decorator, aurelia, bindable

I've either encountered a bug in Aurelia or failed to create a class decorator. Since it requires a fair amount of code to describe and re-create I've created a

[gist.run](https://gist.run/?id=9a91abfff1e325523753ad7235078bcc)

with further information and instructions.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Would you post the original, non-transpiled code, please.

Comment: @AshleyGrant The (relevant) non-transpiled code can also be found in the gist.run, in the .ts files.

Comment: Perhaps this could be due to the following issue: https://github.com/aurelia/binding/issues/316 ?